# How to trigger an animation by PERCENTAGE in swift?

Tags: swift

Alright, I am trying to trigger an animation incrementally as a scroll view is scrolled. To do this, I have taken this link here and converted it to swift - http://www.oliverfoggin.com/controlling-animations-with-a-uiscrollview/

Giving me the percentage offset x for my scrollview. This is all great.

Problem is I'm fairly new to swift and don't know how to tie this back into my existing animation which is a transform/move instead of changing color.

Here's my animation here-

```
self.borderlines.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.01), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
self.activeBorder.layer.opacity = 1

CATransaction.begin()
self.activeBorder.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.03), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
let anim2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
let fromTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.01), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
let toTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(1.0), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
anim2.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: fromTransform)
anim2.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: toTransform)
anim2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
anim2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
anim2.removedOnCompletion = false
self.activeBorder.layer.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: "_activeBorder")

CATransaction.commit()
```

And then I also have another move animation. As is these are called on touch, so 1 static event.

The guy in the tutorial from what I can see recalculated/triggers his animation EVERY scroll then alters bg color by percentage. I don't know how to apply this to another type of animation- he mentions key frames and I have no idea what those are.

How can I achieve this effect? What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 2):

Look into "freezing" your animation by setting its layer's `speed` to zero and manipulating its `timeOffset` as your response to scrolling.

Comment: Downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p160frozenAnimation/FrozenAnimationTest/ViewController.swift It's a slider, not a scroll view, but the principle is the same.